# what is guid for call interrupt in eventOccurred method-Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I am having trouble in performing some activity when a call interrupt comes on blackberry 9105.

Is there any way to know what is the guid when a call interrupt comes in.  I can't find it in the blackberry docs.

```
public void eventOccurred( long guid, int data0, int data1, Object object0, Object object1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a [PhoneListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/PhoneListener.html)?